# Undefined logger in firebase function

Tags: node.js, swift, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send push notifications to firebase using swift, node.js and firebase functions. I can successfully push some of my notifications however I am having a hard time with my messages.

my firebase functions look like,

[image: image 1]

my functions in node.js look like,

```
exports.observeMessages = functions.database.ref('/messages/{fromId}/{toId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

  const fromId = snapshot.val().fromId;
  const toId = snapshot.val().toId;

  console.log('LOGGER --- uid is ' + fromId);
  console.log('LOGGER --- workerId is ' + toId)
})
```

these messages are stored in firebase like,

[image: image 2]

I have tried to send these push notifications with

```
  var toId = context.params.toId;
  var fromId = context.params.fromId;
```

When I post the latter in my node.js code, I see

[image: image 3]

below is how I am sending the message information to firebase

```
    fileprivate func sendMessageWithProperties(_ properties: [String: Any]) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("messages")
    let childRef = ref.childByAutoId()
    let toId = user!.uid!
    let fromId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let timestamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
    
    var values: [String: Any] = ["toId": toId, "fromId": fromId, "timestamp": timestamp, "checked": 0]
    
 
    properties.forEach({values[$0] = $1})
    
    childRef.updateChildValues(values) { (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        
        self.inputContainerView.inputTextField.text = nil
        
        guard let messageId = childRef.key else { return }
        
        let userMessagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(fromId).child(toId).child(messageId)
        userMessagesRef.setValue(1)
        
        let recipientUserMessagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(toId).child(fromId).child(messageId)
        recipientUserMessagesRef.setValue(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue might be in `ref('/messages/{fromId}/{toId}')`. As you want to fire the function when a new message is added in the `messages` array, try changing it to `ref('/messages/{messageId}')`.

```
exports.observeMessages = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

  const fromId = snapshot.val().fromId;
  const toId = snapshot.val().toId;

  console.log('LOGGER --- uid is ' + fromId);
  console.log('LOGGER --- workerId is ' + toId)
})
```

Comment: so my export should look like ref('/messages/{messageId}/{toId}/{fromId}').onCreate or just simply what you put as ref('/messages/{messageId}')??

Comment: I have updated my question to show the method I use to save the data into firebase.

Comment: Such a simple fix that kept me lagged for a while! Thank you so much.